# Приложение - это сравнительный оборот?

Tags: приложение, сравнительный-оборот

> В Приморском крае Дальнего Востока, **как в восточной причудливой сказке**, всё волшебно и восхитительно.

Чем является выделенный фрагмент текста? Сравнительным оборотом? Приложением? Или приложение == сравнительному обороту? Ведь данную часть предложения можно рассматривать как: "все волшебно и восхитительно (почему?), потому что Приморский край - восточная причудливая сказка", "все волшебно и восхитительно (словно как?), словно в восточной причудливой сказке".

Comment: Вам нужно прочитать, что такое приложение: https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/prilozhenie.html

Comment: Никаких отношений "почему?" здесь и близко нет.

Comment: Смысловая схема такая: *Здесь, как там, вот так.* А вы навыдумывали отношения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это статья с другого ресурса. Там я формулирую тему обобщенно и кратко, а сам ответ – это всего три строчки. Материал дан только как справочный **взамен удаленного ответа** (обсуждать не надо).

**Сравнительный оборот как член предложения**

```
            Всего-то и надо было, что ***погуглить…*** (из ответов на форуме)
```

Не стоит думать, что русский язык — это скучно и неинтересно. На некоторых форумах при решении спорных вопросов участники сражаются как гладиаторы на арене или как средневековые рыцари. Страсти порой кипят нешуточные…

**ВОПРОС.** Каким членом предложения является сравнительный оборот?
*В Приморском крае Дальнего Востока, **как в восточной причудливой сказке,** всё волшебно и восхитительно.*

**1. Как решается этот вопрос в школе**

Это надо узнавать в самой школе или искать в школьных учебниках. **Можно предположить,** что он решается просто: сравнительный оборот является обстоятельством (это видно по союзу КАК). Там и не требуется более сложное решение, так как в школе даются **базовые знания.**

**2. Что можно найти в Сети**

Если «просто погуглить», то  обнаружится **очень широкий спектр мнений**, как то:  сравнительный оборот является: (1) обстоятельством, (2) чаще обстоятельством, (3) определением, (4) обстоятельством,  определением или входит в состав сказуемого. Надо сказать, что мнения эти часто никак не доказываются,  а источник не дается, так что подходить к ним надо очень осторожно.

**3. А что у лингвистов?**

Приведем решения, взятые из двух вузовских учебников по грамматике.

**(1) Прияткина А. Ф. Русский язык Синтаксис осложненного предложения. 2016 (основная мысль)**

В общем случае **нельзя приравнять** сравнительный оборот к определенному члену предложения, так как у него более сложное строение. Но в трехчастных конструкциях с двойными связями (два предмета/признака сравниваются через действие/состояние) могут проявляться **в большей мере:**

—  **обстоятельственные отношения** (предмет действует как?);

— **признаковые/определительные отношения**  (предмет/признак  какой?).

При обособлении мы подчеркиваем ОПРЕДЕЛИТЕЛЬНОЕ значение, а при отсутствии обособления — ОБСТОЯТЕЛЬСТВЕННОЕ, причем в какой-то мере это зависит от ПОЗИЦИИ оборота в предложении.

**(2) Кустова  Г. И. Синтаксис современного русского языка, стр. 234, 2005 г. (основная мысль и цитаты)**

Здесь  тоже нет формулировки «оборот ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ», но сказано «оборот занимает ПОЗИЦИЮ определенного члена предложения.

Цитаты (в упрощенном виде): [https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf), стр. 120 и 121

В предложении сравнительный оборот **занимает позицию:**

— именной части сказуемого: Лед {был) как стекло;

— обстоятельства: Он проспал, и теперь мчался на лекцию, как метеор;

— определения (приложения): Но голос мой, как воздух свежий, Пропел давно, замолк давно .

Сравнительные  обороты могут иметь **двойные семантические связи** (с существительным и со сказуемым). В этом случае они  по структуре близки к **сочинительному ряду,** так как состоят из одинаковых (параллельных) форм, однако связь между этими формами осуществляет **подчинительный союз** (союз «как», а также другие союзы-синонимы).

**РЕШЕНИЕ ЗАДАЧИ**

В приведенном предложении сравниваются **два предмета** (Приморский край и сказка) через **предикативный признак/состояние** (волшебно и восхитительно). Но использована не начальная форма существительных (что?), а их **падежная форма**  (где?), поэтому оборот **ближе к обстоятельству.**

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146127/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0):

В таком предложении: Он, как ошпаренный, бежал – сочетание ‟как ошпаренный” является сравнительным оборотом. В вашем предложении: ‟В Приморском крае Дальнего Востока как в восточной причудливой сказке: всё волшебно и восхитительно” – сочетание ‟как в восточной причудливой сказке” является сказуемым, а сочетание ‟всё волшебно и восхитительно” – второе предложение в сложном предложении с бессоюзной связью, где второе предложение раскрывает содержание первой части. [Ссылка на тему про бессоюзные.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150)

**В Приморском крае Дальнего Востока [обстановка / всё / атмосфера] как в восточной причудливой сказке: всё волшебно и восхитительно.**