# Сравнительный оборот или обстоятельство образа действия с «как»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сравнительный-оборот, обстоятельство

[У Розенталя в статье о сравнительных оборотах](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147,3) есть следующие примеры:

> Я относился к нему, как к брату — ‘по-братски’;

> Он работал, как батрак — ‘много’, ‘подобно батраку’.

Тут прямо в кавычках указаны синонимичные выражения, являющиеся обстоятельствами образа действия: «по-братски» и «много». Почему тогда оборот обособляется, хотя по правилу оборот с союзом «как» в роли обстоятельства образа действия не обособляется?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо отличать **тождество** (приравнивание) от **сравнения** (уподобления).

**ОБЩАЯ ТЕОРИЯ**

**1. Тождество:**

*Я относился к нему **как к брату*** (считал своим братом)

*Он работал **как батрак*** (работал батраком).

**2.  Сравнение**

**[Теория:  Сравнительный оборот как член предложения.](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473791/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82)**

В общем случае нельзя приравнять сравнительный оборот к **определенному члену** предложения, так как у него более сложное строение. Но **в трехчастных конструкциях с двойными связями** (два предмета/признака сравниваются через действие/состояние) могут проявляться в большей мере:

— **обстоятельственные** отношения (предмет действует как?);

— **признаковые/определительные** отношения (предмет/признак какой?).

При обособлении мы подчеркиваем **определительное** значение, а при отсутствии обособления — **обстоятельственное**, причем в какой-то мере это зависит от **ПОЗИЦИИ** оборота в предложении.

(1) ***Я относился к нему, как к брату.***

Два лица (он  и брат) сравниваются через действие (относился), но использована **не начальная** форма существительных (кто?), а их **падежная форма** (к кому?), поэтому оборот обособляется.
Сравнить: *Я любил его как брата* (возможен вариант без обособления).

(2) **Варианты:** *Он работал **как батрАк**. Он рабОтал,  **как батрАк.***

Два лица сравниваются через действие (работал). Возможны как обстоятельственные (как?), так и определительные (как кто?) отношения. Выбор варианта зависит от позиции оборота и структуры предложения.

**ПРАКТИКА ПИСЬМА**

Про наличии **повтора** (он — брат, к нему — к брату, я — батрак) сравнительный оборот обычно **обособляется**. При этом обособлении тем вероятнее, чем ближе оборот к подлежащему. При смещении к концу предложения обстоятельственное значение более возможно, тогда  **ударение** падает только на оборот.

Сравнить: *Я работал **как батрАк**. — Я рабОтал, // как батрАк.*

В конечном итоге все зависит **от структуры** предложения и расстановки **ударений** в нем.

**ПРИМЕРЫ**

*Я не ваше пропиваю, я вам все сполна отдаю, **как батрАк** на вас работаю!* (Пример из Накорпуса.).

*Я **как батрАк** работаю, да вам все мало.*

*Работаю на вас **как батрАк**, а благодарности нет*.

*Я, **как батрАк**, один на всю семью рабОтаю, а вы все попрекаете!*

Comment: В конечном итоге требуется написать сотни три предложений с оборотом КАК, где он выступает либо как часть сказуемого, либо как а как b, либо как а = b,  либо как оборот со значением уподобления и всё это прокомментировать самому для себя, чтобы это в конце концов отложилось.)

Comment: Да,  вы правы, изучить тему по справочнику сложно.  Здесь нужно использовать все: современную теорию сравнительных оборотов, интонационный и структурный анализ как дополнение к семантическому анализу. И практика! А еще  важно слышать предложение, просто прочитывать его вслух. Несколько раз иногда!  Добавление даже одного слова может изменить равновесную структуру, и тогда решение изменится.  Я много работала с этой темой,  но она бесконечна)  Что-то все равно еще не понято, тайны остаются.

Comment: Хочу уточнить значение сравнительного оборота с постановкой запятой: «Он работал, как батрак». Это означает: «Он работал таким же образом, как это делает батрак»? Сравнительный оборот модифицирует сказуемое. Или же это означает: «Он работал, и батрак работает»? Сравнительный оборот не модифицирует сказуемое, а просто попутно указывает на то, что это же действие/состояние есть и у другого предмета.

Я правильно понимаю, что бывает и так и так?

Comment: Да,  бывает и так и так.  С одной стороны, здесь много ЧАСТНЫХ деталей, которые надо учитывать. С другой стороны, необходимо видеть ОБЩИЙ алгоритм решения. Сравнительный оборот — трехчастная конструкция, а это предполагает наличие ДВУХ решений в любом случае.  Мы делаем выбор между определительным значением (он как батрак, обособление) и обстоятельственным значением (работал как батрак)  оборота.  То есть сравниваем слова со значением лица через ДЕЙСТВИЕ. Такое понимание очень важно, а иначе нет общего ориентира.  А вот выбор уже зависит от семантики, структуры предложения и оборота и т.д.

Comment: @Sharon Шерон, как всегда, вы даёте уникальные объяснения. Вы не просто делаете топорный анализ по статье из справочника Лопатина или Розенталя, а комбинируете в своём разборе правила из совершенно разных разделов языкознания.

Comment: Спасибо!  Хорошо, что мы понимаем друг друга)