# Разве не выделяется сравнительный оборот?

Tags: сравнение

> "И () как ребенок () с детворой, и () как ребенок () с детворой ты лепишь
> бабу снежную".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В зависимости от смысла, вкладываемого в этот текст, возможны такие варианты:

*И, как ребенок, с детворой, и, как ребенок, **с детворой ты** лепишь бабу снежную.*

*И, как ребенок с детворой, и, как **ребенок с детворой**, ты лепишь бабу снежную.*

При необособлении же оборота будет непонятно, в какое словосочетание попадает  вот это «с детворой» — то ли «ребенок с детворой», то ли «ты с детворой»…

Comment: Интонация в первом варианте перечислительная? Запятые после каждого слова...

Comment: @Sharon:  _«Интонация в первом варианте перечислительная? Запятые после каждого слова...»_ === Ну и что, что после каждого слова? Зато смысл понятен, на что **в первую очередь** и надо обращать внимание. А не на ударения! Кстати, первый вариант тоже можно найти в Сети.

Comment: И по смыслу вопрос. Одно лицо (ты) сравнивается со всей компанией (ребенок с детворой)?

Comment: По одному смыслу запятые не ставят, учитывают все сразу: семантика + грамматика + интонация.  Здесь гармония нужна и единство трех принципов)  А то такое можно только по смыслу понаставить, что мама не горюй.  В Сети же много чего можно найти: народ простой, знаки ставить не все умеют.

Comment: @Sharon: _«В Сети же много чего можно найти: народ простой…»_  === К сожалению, и на этом сайте (в том числе и в Ваших ответах!) _много чего_ можно найти… 

Comment: @Sharon: _«И это все ваши доводы? А как же про грамматику сравнительных оборотов, так ничего и не скажете? Вы по каким книгам эту тему изучали? Про интонацию я уж не буду спрашивать.»_ === 

Answer (score 1):

```
 Там нет меня, где дым волос не затуманит белый день,
 Где сосны от янтарных слёз утрет заботливый олень.
 Я только там, где ты порой на дверь глядишь с надеждою,
 И как ребёнок с детворой ты лепишь бабу снежную.
 
               Композитор И. Николаев, слова П. Жагуна
```

Рассмотрим предложение: *И **как ребЁнок** с детворой / ты лепишь бАбу снежную.*

1. Стоит ли удивляться тому, что сравнительный оборот **не обособлен?** Разве сравнительный оборот всегда обособляется?

Это **классический (трехчастный)** оборот, где два лица (ты и ребенок) сравниваются через отношение к действию (лепишь). Такие обороты обособляются часто, но все же не всегда. При обособлении мы подчеркиваем **сравнение** (ты, как ребенок), а необособленный оборот является **обстоятельством** образа действия: лепишь как ребенок. При решении учитывается влияние различных **факторов** (структура предложения, расположение оборота и т.д.).

О трехчастной конструкции оборота: **темы [1](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473791/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82) и [2](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474228/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8/474260#comment507015_474260).**

2. В данном случае следует **учесть:** (1) стихотворный **ритм** и (2) **инверсию** слов в структуре предложения.

В заданном предложении сочетание "и как ребёнок с детворой" является единой фонетической фразой, что **препятствует обособлению** оборота "как ребенок". Ударение падает на оборот, а сказуемое находится в безударной позиции. При такой структуре оборот может быть только **обстоятельством**.

Итак, это простое предложение **без обособления**. Интонационно такое предложение делится **на две части,** поэтому скорее всё сочетание "И как ребёнок с детворой" можно было бы обособить. Но и этого нет, логически первая часть никак **не выделена.**

**О ПЕСНЕ**

https://yandex.ru/video/preview/17039748348705186585

**[Статья](https://dzen.ru/a/Xqmw0-vM7h6Ysvid):**   *В интернете я видела разбор текста песни лингвистом, который разнес строчки в пух и прах. Но тем не менее, песня живет и радует слушателей. Ее авторство приписывают **Игорю Николаеву,** но, те, кто знаком с творчеством этого композитора, знают, что это не так. Текст написан российским художником, поэтом и музыкантом — **Павлом Жагуном**.*

Да, песня воспринимается неоднозначно...

Comment: Мне здесь иная видится структура. Лепишь (с кем) с детворой, поэтому детвору сразу отбрасываем в сторону. Лепишь (как кто, подобно кому), как ребенок. Разве может ритм влиять на пунктуацию? Не думаю, что лепишь ребенком, лепишь по-детски, тут будет уместно сказать... То есть в том случае, если б я обособила, было бы ошибкой?

Comment: Отбрасывать ничего нельзя, искажаете структуру заданного предложения.  Но именно эта структура учитывается при обособлении. А грамматика такая: лепишь (как?) как ребенок, по-детски,  лепишь ( кем?)  с детворой. Обособление будет ошибкой.

Comment: Можно сравнить: Ты, как ребЕнок, с детворой лепИл бы бабу снежную. Оборот расположен сразу за подлежащим, его можно обособить.  Два ударения: на обороте и на сказуемом.